# Understanding statement of an exercise from Humphreys: Root systems and Weyl groups

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

Following Humphrey's Lie algebra, a root system $\Phi$ of the Eucludean space $E_n$ (with inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$) is a set of vectors in $E_n$ satisfying following:

(1) $\Phi$ contains non-zero vectors, and generates the space $E_n$.

(2) If $\alpha\in \Phi$ then $-\alpha\in \Phi$ and these are the only multiples of $\alpha$ which are in $\Phi$.

(3) If $\alpha,\beta\in \Phi$ then $\langle \beta,\alpha\rangle:=2(\beta,\alpha)/(\alpha,\alpha)$ is an integer.

The subgroup of orthogonal group $O(n)$ generated by reflections $\sigma_{\alpha}$, $\alpha\in\Phi$is called Weyl group of $\Phi$.

For every $\alpha\in\Phi$, let $\alpha^*=2\alpha/(\alpha,\alpha)$. Then $\Phi^*=\{ \alpha^* : \alpha\in \Phi\}$ is called dual of $\Phi$.

**Exercise:** Show that $\Phi^*$ is a root system , whose Weyl group is naturally isomorphic to Weyl group of $\Phi$.

**My answer:** I verified the above axioms of root system for $\Phi^*$. Next, for $\alpha\in\Phi$, since $\alpha^*=2\alpha/(\alpha,\alpha)$, a multiple of $\alpha$. Hence reflection $\sigma_{\alpha}$ in $\alpha$ and the reflection $\sigma_{\alpha^*}$ in $\alpha^*$ is *same(equal)*; so Weyl groups are *equal*.

**Q.1.** Am I right? I wondered why it is asked to prove that they are *naturally isomorphic* rather than to prove that *they are equal(same)*?

**Q.2** Some places, the dual root system is defined by considering dual space of $E_n$; then is that notion equivalent to the Humphrey's notion of dual root system?

Comment: Reflection $\sigma_{\alpha}$ means following: $\alpha$ is non-zero vector in Euclidean space $E_n$; take hyperplane orthogonal to that $\alpha$. then $\sigma_{\alpha}$ is reflection in that hyperplane.

Comment: For future readers: Q.1.: you are right. They are equal.